# Как в реакте узнать, что компонент промонтировался?

Tags: reactjs

есть такой код:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ContentIndex from '../pages/ContentIndex';
import Catalog from '../pages/Catalog';

class Root extends Component {
  
  render(){
      return(
      <div className="all-data">
   <Switch>

    <Route
    exact
    path={"/"}
    component={ContentIndex}
    />

    <Route
    path={'/catalog'
    component={Catalog}
    />
              
              </Switch>
       </div>

      )
  }

}
```

Нужно как-то реализировать такой шаблон чтобы при переходе по url загружался спиннер и после того, когда компонент промонтировался он прятался

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать событие `componentDidMount`, которое происходит при монтировании компонента. Устанавливаете состояние "загрузки" `isFetching: true`, после загрузки устанавливаете `isFetching: false`. В зависимости от этого состояния в рендере отрисовываете либо прогресс либо основной компонент.

```
class Catalog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isFetching: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // устанавливаем состояние "загрузка"
        this.setState({
            isFetching: true
        });

        // Грузим данные
        functionToLoadData(url)
            .onSuccess(() = {
                // По окончании загрузки убираем состояние "загрузка"
                this.setState({
                    isFetching: false
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.isFetching && 
                <SomeProgressComponent/>
            }
            {!this.state.isFetching && 
                <div>
                    Основной компонент каталога
                </div>
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: это для 1-го конкретного компонента, а мне нужно шаблон для многих компонент, т.е. нужно кормить компонент в функцию, а она показывает загрузчик пока компонент рисуеться примерно так: <Route
    exact
    path={"/"}
    component={loadComponent( ContentIndex ) }
    />

Comment: И как `loadComponent` узнает логику отрисовки компонента? Загрузка с сервера функция асинхронная. Компонент примонтируется раньше чем вы получите данные с сервера и выдаст ошибку отрисовки неполученных данных

Comment: я хочу сделать что-то на подобии instagram смены url, у них как-то работает

Comment: смена урл никак не связана с монтированием компонента.